# When i use Java for my Linux or Windows PC. Which JVM it use? Is it j9 or JamVM or Squeak?

Tags: java, jvm

When i use Java, in my Linux box generally i install OpenJDK using package manager. And for Windows i use Sun official downloads.

But i am not sure which JVM exactly it use? (For some memory issues). Does it use

- j9 for Sun default JVM?
- or it use JamVM
- or it use Squeak?

What does it use when i use OpenJDK under linux and the default Sun download under Windows? Does all JVM available for 8bit to 64bit platforms (open source to use them or commercial)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is d) none of the above.

Both the official Java packages, and OpenJDK use Sun / Oracle's "official" JVM, which I believe is called *HotSpot*. This is **not** J9, that's IBM's implementation, which you're unlikely to use on a typical Windows or Linux box. I've never heard of *JamVM*; the only *Squeak* I know of is a Smalltalk implementation, which has nothing to do with Java.